# How do I edit the php.ini file?

Tags: php, macos, xampp

Is there any way to modify the php.ini file in Mac OSX.. I'm using XAMPP and i need to change the upload-tmp-dir path. Whenever I try to edit and save the file, it shows some error that I am not authorised to do so.
Please help!

Comment: What if you try to copy php.ini file to your Desktop, make changes, save it, and replace back?

Comment: Launch terminal, go to the path and do `sudo nano php.ini`

Comment: Then I'll post it as answer ;))

Comment: But my uploads are still not working.. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you try to copy php.ini file to your Desktop, make changes, save it, and replace back?

Answer (score 1):

You can update using editor in terminal and use sudo command to open it as superuser, see [here](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo.man.html).

```
sudo vim php.ini
```

or

```
sudo emacs php.ini
```

Your choice

Answer (score 0):

1.open php.ini with superuser

```
sudo vim php.ini
```

2.press i to change somthing

3.press Esc and :wq to save and exit

4.restart your web server

Maybe step 4 is the reason "But my uploads are still not working.. ".